# split test/train data has inconsistent number of samples when using xgboost

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, xgboost

I am new to machine learning so be gentle. I have a single csv file for data, that I would like to split into test/train data. I have used the following code to split the data

```
raw_data1. drop('Income_Weekly', axis=1, inplace=True) 

df = raw_data1

df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)

msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.5

X_train = df[msk]
y_train = df[~msk]
```

However, when trying to apply the xgboost algorithm, I receive an error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4791, 5006]
```

The error occurs at the line:

```
random_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

My complete code is as follows:

```
import xgboost
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

classifier=xgboost.XGBRegressor()
regressor=xgboost.XGBRegressor() 

booster=['gbtree','gblinear']
base_score=[0.25,0.5,0.75,1]

## Hyper Parameter Optimization
#

n_estimators = [100, 500, 900, 1100, 1500]
max_depth = [2, 3, 5, 10, 15]
booster=['gbtree','gblinear']
learning_rate=[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.20]
min_child_weight=[1,2,3,4]

# Define the grid of hyperparameters to search
hyperparameter_grid = {
    'n_estimators': n_estimators,
    'max_depth':max_depth,
    'learning_rate':learning_rate,
    'min_child_weight':min_child_weight,
    'booster':booster,
    'base_score':base_score
    }

random_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=regressor,
            param_distributions=hyperparameter_grid,
            cv=5, n_iter=50,
            scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error',n_jobs = 4,
            verbose = 5, 
            return_train_score = True,
            random_state=42)

random_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current mask and splitting method results in two different size dataframes which can't be compared with xgboost, they should be the same size.

Maybe change the splitting code to use sklearn's train test split.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[list_x_cols], df['y_col'],test_size=0.2)
```

Looks like you are using a random number to split the set, you can change test_size to use a random number if you want but 0.2/ 0.3/ 0.33 are used often.

list_x_cols should contain all your feature columns e.g. df['xvar1', 'xvar2', 'xvar3', ...].

To the test if the shape of your split is not aligned, the following code can be used. Please share the outcome of the print statements:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

if X_train.shape[0] != y_train.shape[0]:
  print("X and y rows imbalanced")
```

Comment: Hi @stijn, thanks for the response. I did try that as well as other percentage splits however it didn't change anything as the sample was still imbalanced. What do you mean by using list_x_cols and y_col? As in I should list the feature columns in list_x_cols and the target in y col?

Comment: Is it a publicly available dataset? I could have a look. But the problems seems to be that you have more rows for y_train (5006) than for X_train (4791) where they should be equal. I edited my original answer with some code you can use to check the shape of the splitted df.

Comment: @lambda Currently unable to have a look on discord, I am at work. Are you still using test train split and both the msk or just the msk for splitting? Otherwise you can try to remove the msk and see what happens, so no more transformations after the test train split function.